# Efficiency: Check if value in Pandas DataFrame has changed with an specific threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column which a sensor recorded. 
This Data has some noise on it, so the values are not exactly the same for each point of time while nothing was detected.
I want to split that recorded DataFrame into new DataFrames only containing the "interesting" Data (with values bigger than a certain threshold of column 'B', in this example bigger than 5). 
In this example 'A' represents a timestamp, and 'B' represents the sensor data, with noise.
The desired outcome of this example would be two DataFrames. One with the rows from 5 to 6, the other one with the rows from 10 to 12. 
A normal loop over the DataFrame is very time consuming, as the DataFrame has ~24mio rows. Is there a efficient way to deal with such an issue in pandas or similar?

Edit:

Example:

```
# |  A  |  B  
--+-----+-----
1 |  1  |  0.10
2 |  2  |  0.11
3 |  3  |  0.09
4 |  4  |  0.12
5 |  5  |  5.24
6 |  6  |  6.33
7 |  7  |  0.08
8 |  8  |  0.09
9 |  9  |  0.10
10|  10 |  7.54
11|  11 |  8.33
12|  12 |  9.03
13|  13 |  0.43
```

Comment: please be more precise in what you want as outcome; 
seperate datafames for consecutive rows where values are greater than 5? 
or dataframe where row 'b' value is between 5 and 7, and another for rows with values between 7 and 10?

Comment: @Chrisvdberge: I want seperate dataframes for everytime the "action" happened during my measurements. So basically the sensor was activated... Than after couple of minutes (thousand of rows) the first action occured for about 1 min. During that "action" the values of 'B' can get any value. Afterwards the action finished, there is a couple of minutes break again. Than the next action occurs for ~1min, than break, action, break and so on.
I want seperated dataframes for each action. The problem with the answers below is, that the threshold also filters out values below the threshold that

Comment: occured during the event...
I hope that description makes things clearer. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: @Chrisvdberge: I just created a new question for this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096992/efficiency-check-if-value-in-pandas-dataframe-has-changed-with-an-specific-thre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
thresh = 5
s = df['B'].lt(thresh)

for k, v in (df.assign(c=s.cumsum())
               .loc[~s]
               .groupby('c')
            ):
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
   A     B  c
#            
5  5  5.24  4
6  6  6.33  4
     A     B  c
#              
10  10  7.54  7
11  11  8.33  7
12  12  9.03  7
```

**Option 2**:

```
for k, v in df.loc[~s].groupby(s.cumsum()):
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
   A     B
#         
5  5  5.24
6  6  6.33
     A     B
#           
10  10  7.54
11  11  8.33
12  12  9.03
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! That completely solved the question I asked and is very nice! Nevertheless I found out that my question was formulated wrong. In between the "interesting intervall" it can occur, that the value goes down to zero again, but those are cut out now because of "df2=df[df.B>thresh]". Do you have a solution for that? Thank you :)) PS: I edited the original example

Comment: I just accepted your answer and will write a new question as you were right :) thank you!