# Efficiency: Check if value in Pandas DataFrame has changed with an specific threshold outside an interval of measurement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column which a sensor recorded. 
This Data has some noise on it, so the values are not exactly the same for each point of time while nothing was detected.
I want to split that recorded DataFrame into new DataFrames only containing the "interesting" Data (with values bigger than a certain threshold of column 'B', in this example bigger than 5). 
In this example 'A' represents a timestamp, and 'B' represents the sensor data, with noise.
The desired outcome of this example would be two DataFrames. One with the rows from 5 to 6, the other one with the rows from 10 to 15. 
A normal loop over the DataFrame is very time consuming, as the DataFrame has ~24mio rows. Is there a efficient way to deal with such an issue in pandas or similar?

Example:

```
# |  A  |  B  
--+-----+-----
1 |  1  |  0.10
2 |  2  |  0.11
3 |  3  |  0.09
4 |  4  |  0.12
5 |  5  |  5.24
6 |  6  |  6.33
7 |  7  |  0.08
8 |  8  |  0.09
9 |  9  |  0.10
10|  10 |  7.54
11|  11 |  8.33
12|  12 |  9.03
13|  13 |  1.43
14|  14 |  9.64
15|  15 |  9.03
16|  16 |  0.43
17|  17 |  0.53
18|  18 |  0.62
19|  19 |  0.73
20|  20 |  0.51
```

It can occur, that in between the "interesting interval" a value below the threshold occurs. A indicator of an ended interval would be that 1000 values in a row are below the threshold.

Thank you!

Comment: I want seperate dataframes for everytime the "action" happened during my measurements. So basically the sensor was activated... Than after couple of minutes (thousand of rows) the first action occured for about 1 min. During that "action" the values of 'B' can get any value. Afterwards the action finished, there is a couple of minutes break again. Than the next action occurs for ~1min, than break, action, break and so on. I want seperated dataframes for each action. The problem with the answers below is, that the threshold also filters out values below the threshold that

Comment: The difficult part is that in row 13 your value goes below 5. So following your logic, it would look like it's turning off and on. So is it also possible to assume that `< 1` is turned off, this way row 13 would be marked as turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which is generalisable and tries to catch edge cases:

```
# all rows where B > 5
mask1 = df['B'].gt(5)

# all rows where Bt-1 > 5 & Bt+1 > 5
mask2 = df['B'].shift().gt(5) & df['B'].shift(-1).gt(5)

# all rows where mask1 OR mask2 is True
mask3 = (mask1 | mask2)

# turn rows where mask 3 is False to NaN
mask4 = mask3.astype(int).diff().eq(1).cumsum().where(mask3)

# put each group of turned on sensor into a different dataframe
dfs = [dfg.reset_index(drop=True) for _, dfg in df.groupby(mask4)]
```

**Output**

```
for d in dfs:
    print(d, '\n')

   A    B
4  5 5.24
5  6 6.33 

     A    B
9   10 7.54
10  11 8.33
11  12 9.03
12  13 1.43
13  14 9.64
14  15 9.03
```

Or in a function:

```
def split_turn_on_off(dataframe):
    mask1 = dataframe['B'].gt(5)
    mask2 = dataframe['B'].shift().gt(5) & dataframe['B'].shift(-1).gt(5)
    mask3 = (mask1 | mask2)
    mask4 = mask3.astype(int).diff().eq(1).cumsum().where(mask3)

    # put each group of turned on sensor into a different dataframe
    dataframes = [dataframeg.reset_index(drop=True) for _, dataframeg in dataframe.groupby(mask4)]

    return dataframes
```

Comment: Very nice solution. And I learned new inspiring features for pandas! Thank you very much!